# Use a separate log file for each Pentaho Data Integration Job (kettle)

Tags: logging, pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I would like to have each Job in Pentaho to log execution information a separate log file, instead of having one single file in `/opt/pentaho/server/data-integration-server/logs/pentaho.log`. Does anyone know how to make this happen?

In alternative, is there a good graphical parser I can use to parse the Pentaho data integration log file?

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify the log file by redirecting the output of the kitchen.sh in the command line;

Or you can specify the log file of a sub-job; Just create a wrapper job that accepts as parameter the job or transformation to run and launches it, specifying the log file to create.